# Generate CSV with multiple values in Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

```
{'id': '/en/45_2006', 'type': '/film/film', 'directed_by': ['Gary Lennon'], 'genre': ['Black comedy', 'Thriller', 'Psychological thriller', 'Indie film', 'Action Film', 'Crime Thriller', 'Crime Fiction', 'Drama'], 'name': '.45', 'initial_release_date': '2006-11-30'}
```

I have a list of such dictionaries from which I want to create a CSV file.

The following code seems to work fine. But when the dictionary has multiple values for a key (list) it writes the entire list as it is-

```
    keys = ['name', 'directed_by', 'genre', 'type', 'id', 'initial_release_date']
    with open('film.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(filmlist)
```

How should I write the CSV files given the fact that certain keys have multiple values in a list and I want to write all of them.

Comment: Do you want to duplicate each row for each genre in the list of genres? That is, do you want multiple entries for each movie, each entry having only one genre?

Comment: No I don't want to duplicate rows. I want it in the same row and be able to use another delimiter for distinguishing multiple values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extension of jonrsharpes answer to take care of a special delimiter for your lists:

```
special_delim = '%'
for k, v in d.items():
     if isinstance(v, list):
        d[k] = special_delim.join(v)
```

Comment: You might need `special_delim.join(map(str, v))` to ensure non-string list contents don't break the code

Comment: This is what I had also done. Looks like you can't do it in 1 go. So this should be the way it can be implemented.

Comment: You are right. In the problem description all genres are strings, this is the more general solution for arbitrary types. However, if it is guaranteed to contain only strings then one would not need to map over all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert all lists into strings first:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        d[k] = str(v)
```

and use `ast.literal_eval` to retrieve the list when you read the `csv` file back in.

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what the default implementation does. Your solution would work if I was reading it back into python. But I need to be able to split it into multiple values by another CSV parser